# BarChart with MPAndroidChart : bars are invisible

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart to generate a simple bar chart, inside a collapsing toolbar. When I add entries, the value of the entry is visible at the correct height on the chart, but I can't see the bar.

This is how I create my variables:

```
final List<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
final BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, getResources().getString(R.string.cycles_profiled));
final BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
```

This is how I populate the data and refresh the chart:

```
final Calendar cal = getFirstDayOfWeek();
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_DAYS; i++) {
    long date = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(date, map.get(date)));
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
}
barDataSet.setValues(barEntries);
barChart.setData(barData);
barData.notifyDataChanged();
barChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
barChart.invalidate();
```

[image: Graph]

I have no problem creating bar charts in other parts of my app. When I draw linecharts inside the collapsing toolbar, it also works fine.

Comment: Have you tried `barChart.setHardwareAccelerationEnabled(false);`?

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, but the result is the same

Comment: What version of the MPAndroidChart is this? Is the result on all phones, or is it on just one phone?

Comment: Very hard to debug from here. Make sure you have the latest version of the library and try creating a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am using the latest version of the library, 3.0.1. The result is the same on all devices. Okay thanks for the advice I will try that!

Comment: Also, how are you setting the background color to blue?

Comment: I am not setting it to blue, the background is part of the (collapsing) toolbar my chart is in.

Comment: That was a really important detail you left out of your question! That's why it's important to create a MCVE

Comment: thank you, I edited the question.

Comment: this is still not an MCVE. We don't mnow what class your collapsing toolbar is. So how can we help? If you want the issue to go further create the _minimum_ activity to reproduce the issue and post it here. Otherwise we just have to guess what is wrong

Comment: @apat: have you found the solution? I face the same issue...

Comment: @androfan No I haven't found the solution, sorry. Is your graph also in a collapsing toolbar?

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue, solved it thanks to [OumaSyuu](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2892).
For some reason the `BarChart` has a difficulty with milliseconds.. convert your milliseconds to minutes: `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisecondValue)` and your life will be honey!

- If converting to minutes doesn't help try to a different (higher) time unit. The time unit that will be good for you is the average gap between the bars, for me it was hours.

  - Another interesting point that may help you style the chart - In the method `setBarWidth(float mBarWidth)`, the input `mBarWidth` represent values not pixels.

Answer (score 4):

i was facing the same issue when i used timestamp for X axis values which was reported as a bug in the library, so i came out with the following solution

first create an arraylist:

```
ArrayList<String> xAxis_stringArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then while you add the entries to the entry list, set the x value to be the index of the data source (string value) and add the string value to the string array like that:

`jsonObject = results.getJSONObject(index);
 String s = jsonObject.getString(x);
 xAxis_stringArray.add(s);
 entries.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(index), Float.valueOf(jsonObject.getString(y))));`

and finally refer the xAxis to the value formatter class:

```
XAxis xAxis = sum_chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new TimeAxisValueFormatter(xAxis_stringArray));
```

TimeAxisValueFormatter class:

```
public class TimeAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public TimeAxisValueFormatter(ArrayList<String> list) {
    this.arrayList = list;
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    return arrayList.get(Math.round(value));
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to set **.setColor**

Try with

```
barDataSet.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0)); //Put your RGB Color
```

Comment: No actually I do it, I just havent posted the code, but I do :

Comment: I do: barDataSet.setColor(Color.WHITE)

Comment: This is not the same problem as mine, as my chart is being displayed. Moreover, the width and height of the chart are set in the XML.

Comment: Color.WHITE is already an actual color.
I have tried using one of my own colors and getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor) but the result is the same.

Comment: @apat any clue ??

Comment: No I have no idea. I draw other barcharts in my app and I don't have any problem. Just this one, in a collapsing toolbar, doesn't show the bars.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just now, for me increasing the barwidth solved the problem. I think the problem lays with how spread out your data is which impacts the width of the lines. If you have a dataset that is only spread out over an hour and has entry for every minute of that hour, I think this problem won't exist. But if you are like me and have sparse data over 5 hours or so, then the barwidth just become smaller and smaller to accommodate all those entries and the bar just disappears.

Example:

```
        data.setBarWidth(2f);
```

[image]

When I increased the barwidth to 80f:

```
        data.setBarWidth(80f);
```

[image]